# What's the difference between a web server and a real(physical) server?

Tags: server, webserver

So,I am a rookie to web development and things about servers keep disturbing me.According to my understanding,a web server is an application used to interact with a browser.A physical server is a hardware,is an equipment.I don't reallt see the connections between these two.Would it be right for me to understand that a web server is an application designed to run on a physical server?

Answer (score 0):

It would. A physical server is just a computer. Not sure what else to say :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that's it, yes.

A physical server is a computer that is set up to serve some data. Often it is build of hardware that is constructed specially for this task... 19' rack, hard disks that are fast and reliable...

A software server is a programm that listens for incoming requests and reacts in some way - sending back a file, passing the request to a background programm (apache passing requests that end in .php to the php modules), ...

sometimes the operating system on a computer acting as a server is called server, too...but I think that is just laziness ;)